# what is the difference between these two in c++

Tags: c++

```
char y1[] = "a";

char y2 = "a";
```

for the first one, I don't see any error message on the Visual Studio IDE, but for the second one I got the error message of: 
error C2440:  'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [2]' to 'char'

Is it possible to know the difference between the two?
Also if they are different, what properties are different between them?

I was reading that if you have double quote, then it is a string literal, but if you have a single quote, then it is a single character.

Also I was reading that with the symbol of [], the char y1[] is considered as an array?

I am kind of confused with the above. Could someone kindly explain and give some simple and clear examples for clarification.

Also if the above are indeed different, how about the following:

```
char y1[]='a';
char y1[]="a"; /* this is double quotation*/

char y2 = 'a';   
char y2 = "a"; /* this is double quotation and without the []*/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"a"` This is an example of a **String Literal** in C++ and in C. This is used to store many characters e.g. `"abcdefg"`.

A string literal always has the last character as `\0` which is the classical C definition of a string.

As you already mentioned, `char y1[]` indicates an array of characters. This can be assigned to a string literal. e.g.

`char y1[] = "abcd";`

In such a case, `y1` is defined to have a size of 5 characters and has a `\0` at the end. The raw C string `"abcd"` is copied into the array.

> char y2 = "a";

A string literal cannot be assigned to a single character as you have the `'\0` at the end.

---

`'a'` is a **Character Literal** in C++ and C. It is used to store a single character.

> char y1[]='a';

This is not allowed as you are assigning a single character literal to an array.

> char y1[]="a"; /* this is double quotation*/

This is allowed as seen above.

> char y2 = 'a';

You are assigning a character literal to a single character variable so this is OK.

> char y2 = "a"; /* this is double quotation and without the []*/

This is not OK as you are assigning a string literal to a character variable. There is no space for the ending `\0`

Answer (score 3):

In C++ there are different ways of dealing with character strings. First things first, instead of dealing with a raw character string, prefer to use a string object (e.g. [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)).

**Example I:**

```
char y1 = 'a';
```

This is called a single character literal and by convention it is defined by using a *single* quote. The corresponding hex value of it is then assigned.

**Example II:**

```
char y1[] = 'a'; // error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal
```

This will result in a compilation error since `y1` is declared as an array, whose size is not yet defined since the single character literal cannot initialize an array.

**Example III:**

```
char y1[]="a";
```

This example declares a string array `y1` on the (local) stack. The array has the size 2 and is terminated with a `\0`. This array can be modified and will be removed once the program leaves the scope this array was declared in.

**Example IV:**

```
char y1 = "a"; // cannot initialize a variable of type 'char' with an lvalue of type 'const char [2]
```

This example will result in a compiler error. The reason is that `"a"` in this case does terminate implicitly with `\0` (so length of 2) but `y1` can only store 1 character.

**Example V:**

```
const char* y1 = "a";
```

This is another proper way of declaring and defining a constant string char array. In this case the array is constant and cannot be modified (which is helpful for identifiers or other string arrays you simply don't want to modify).

You can find a good summary of this also [here](https://icecube.wisc.edu/~dglo/c_class/array_ptr.html)

Comment: Hello, in your Example III, you said "... is not terminated with a \0" ?? Sorry do you mean IT IS terminated with a \0??

Comment: because from the other person's explanations above, it seems that the string literal (i.e. the thing inside the double quotation) always has the \0 at the end.

Comment: @john_w You are correct, there is an error in example III: A string literal is always terminated with a null character, so `"a"` is a two character string.

Comment: You can also see this by the fact that `char a[1] = "a";` produces a compile error. In VS2019 the error states: `a value of type "const char [2]" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char [1]"`

Comment: It was meant to be a sentence for the single quote character. I fixed the example