# C ++ about char and string

Tags: c++

what is `char ctemp = ' ';` and `string stemp = "";` means? when they put `' '` and `" "` inside without writing anything inside? Help please! Will appreciate who answer it.

Comment: char ctemp = ' '; - whitespace character and string stemp = ""; is just an empty string. what else you want to know ?

Comment: can you give an example code using it? Thanks!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57985200/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `char ctemp = ' '` will put the value `' ' (32 in ASCII decimal)` inside the `ctemp` variable. 
The `string stemp = "";` will create an empty string in `stemp`.

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes (`'`) indicate a character literal: a single character. Double quotes (`"`) denote a string literal, i.e: an array of characters.

`' '` is a single space character, while `" "` is a single space character followed by a null terminator, as is customary for C-style strings.

Character literals are directly assignable to `char` variables.

The type of a string literal is `const char[N]`, where `N` is the length of the literal, including the null terminator. In C and C++, a static array *decays* to (is implicitly convertible to) a pointer to the first element, and `std::string` is [constructible from](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) a `const char *` pointer (see constructor (5)), which in C usually means a pointer to an array of characters terminated by a null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
char ctemp = ' ';
```

you are assigning a whitespace character `' '` to `ctemp`.

Here

```
string stemp = "";
```

the initializer `""` creates a empty string.

Answer (score 1):

`' '` is the space character. `""` is an empty string. `" "` is a string that contains only the space character.
Note that a statement like `string stemp = ""` implicitly invokes the `string(char const *)` constructor to create a new string instance from a `char const *` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

the first one means a "whitespace" like when you write something and need to divide the words with the space key. That empty space is still part of the string and so you can say your char is only that empty space.

The second one is of type string but it is even less than a white space. It is a completely empty string.

Answer (score 0):

string is array(collection) of char

```
ctemp = ' '
```

mean whitespace character

```
stemp = ""
```

mean empty string no character in string

you can put ' ' to char variable.
you can put " " to array of char.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the single quote is used to identify the single character, and double quotes are used for string literals. A string literal “x” is a string, it is containing character ‘x’ and a null terminator ‘\0’. So “x” is two-character array in this case.

```
Some Examples:
string s = "" ; => empty string
char s =' ' ;   => space (you should have only one character inside the single quotes)
string s = " " ; => space followed by '\0' character (two character array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace character and empty string. You can see the string as a sequence of characters, but they are two different types